# How can I get the name of the defined class in a parent static method in Groovy

Tags: reflection, groovy, static

Note: I found another answer that suggests that Java would redirect the static method call to it's own class even if it's called on a child class so I guess I need to find a Groovy work-around trick or it's just not going to be doable.

Here's the problem: I created an abstract generic "Launcher" class with a "public static void main". The idea is that you extend it and in your child class you annotate methods like this:

```
@Command("Show an explorere shell")
public dir() {
    "explorer".execute()    
}
```

The parent of this class has a main that goes through, reflects for the @Command annotation and if the method name matches your parameter, executes it.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to tell what the actual, instantiated class is within the parent's static main method.

I'm pretty sure there is a trick somewhere--"this" won't work in statics, stack traces don't contain the actual class, just the parent class, and I can't find any meta-info in the class or MetaClass objects that helps.

Currently I've gotten it to work by hard-coding the name of the child class into the parent's main like this:

```
public class QuickCli {
    public static void main(String[] args} {
        (new HardCodedChildClassName())."${args[0]}"()
    }
}
```

I cut quite a bit out of that, but it's the general idea.  I'd like to replace

```
"new HardCodedChildClassName()"
```

with something that will work for any class that extends this class.

Given the two code snips above, the command would be executed from the command line as:

```
groovy HardCodedChildClassName dir
```

Although I'd prefer not to make all the @Command methods static I could do so if I had to, but currently I'm not even convinced I could make that work.

Comment: Static methods aren't inherited in Java, only hidden-is that what you mean by your edit comment?

Comment: Yes, since static methods aren't inherited, I don't think this would be possible in Java--I'm hoping Groovy has some trick.  Currently my solution is to put a main in my child class that forwards an instance of itself to the parent launcher class, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that's possible.  In any case, it's likely to be an ugly hack if it is.  I'd suggest this alternative:  Rather than using the static `main()` entry point, make `QuickCli` a `Runnable`.  Groovy will automatically create an instance and call `run()` on it when it is launched.

One minor problem here is capturing the command-line arguments.  Groovy handles this by passing them to a constructor with a `String[]` parameter.  The instantiated class needs this constructor to capture the args, but in Java, constructors are not inherited.  Fortunately, Groovy has an [`InheritConstructors`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/InheritConstructors.html) annotation that works around this.

Here's an example of how this would look:

```
class QuickCli implements Runnable {
    def args

    QuickCli(String[] args) {
        this.args = args
    }

    void run() {
        "${args[0]}"()
    }
}


@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class HardCodedChildClassName extends QuickCli {

    @Command("Show an explorere shell")
    public dir() {
        "explorer".execute()    
    }
}
```

Comment: Acutally that's exactly the kind of groovy-based solution I was hoping for, and it works well.  It would be nice if it didn't have to have that annotation... I'm going to look into alternative places Java/groovy might hide them.  i'll leave the question open for a while to give others the chance but I'm not really expecting a better solution than this.